# Java symmetric key file generation and use

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm working on a school homework, in which I'm sending files from one host to another. As a part of it, I need to encrypt the files being sent using symmetric cryptography.

So, I guess there should be a key file that I need to store on both ends. Thus the server uses that key to encrypt and the sender uses the same key to decrypt. The hosts are located on different places.

So, I need a key here, how can I generate this key and also read it from the disk? Or if I'm on a wrong track, I'd appreciate if someone shed some light over here. Thanks.

Comment: For encryption I'd use AES. To generate a key I'd just use an API that offers a cryptographic PRNG and use it to generate as much random data as the keysize. And store the key as hex encoded string.

Answer (score -3):

You can use already existing libraries, or you can write a simple one yourself.
For example, a key you can use:

```
String key = "kA}#rP~McSOF~";
```

The way you can use the key is for example: to encrypt add the char from the key to the char from your file you want to decrypt. Except when the key char is a thilde (`~`), take the complement of the char.

```
String txtToEncrypt = "StackOverflow";
bytes[] encrypted = txtToEncrypt.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++)
{
    int keyIndex = i % key.length();
    int cK = key.charAt(keyIndex);
    int cE = encrypted[i];
    if (cK == '~')
    {
        cE = ~cE;
    } else
    {
        cE = (cE + cK) % 255;
    }
    encrypted[i] = (byte) cE;
}
```

Now it is up to you to find the decrypt algoritm. :D

Comment: That's so weak that I'd call it obfuscation and not encryption.

Comment: That is NOT any sort of encryption that should be used for anything that matters even a little.